# Javascript local (disk) database for nativeapp

Tags: javascript, database, nativeapplication

## javascript #database #nativeapp

Hey there.
So, i'm create a piece of software for the local comunity, i've decided for javascript but now i'm having problems creating a local database...
I've seen projects like sql.js and taffyDB and can't put them to work...

What is the best, easyest way, with no dependencies to store a database with arround 2000 records (list of associates of the local club) in a file? doesn't need to be sqlite or other stroctured database, would be fine with something like csv or jason...
I've spend hours searching, but guess this isn't how people usualy use JS (local app) and there is barely any documentation on projects like the one i mentioned.

So, my questions:
Why can't I use sql.js? Am I just doing something wrong?
other alternatives?

I'll be using Electron to deploy the app, or if possible just the files (like a webapp but with local files)

Bare in mind that altough I'de have some knowlage, I stoped codding for a few years and starting again

Comment: where your app in running? inside a web browser?

Comment: Yes... I can also use Electron, but if it can run directly in any browser would be great.

Comment: what is this electron? If it is a webapplication running on webbrowser you can use browser internal database.

Comment: Well, that would probably be bad the next time someone reinstalls windows...
the database needs to be a file in the same dir then the app for portability.
Electron is a way to make a nativeapp with javascript: http://electron.atom.io/

Comment: found neDB... looks good , but can't download the files, help?
wich one to download?: https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb

Comment: thats a node application. install node server and try to run application.

Comment: Hum... no options avaliable without node.js?

Comment: Can you explain why you decided to make your application in Javascript?

Comment: Hey :p
So I had to move to python
I wanted Javascript cause it's so portable... and will last long, This program will be used for years... They actualy just outdated the first one I made in VB6. 
Only real problem is no local database, so we could use JS for native apps... It's just that powerfull and open